# Push data from MS SQL Server to Web Application

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, web-applications, sql-server-2012

I have MS SQL Server 2012 Express on one end and a Node.JS web application on the other.

I need some way of tracking DML changes (insert, update or delete operations) to given tables.

Update Example:

If a record is updated, I need to send the updated record to my web application (could be a HTTP POST or write data over TCP)

The MS SQL Server is firewalled to prevent direct access nor would I want to poll the database.

How would I go about achieving this on the MS SQL Server end?

Answer (score 0):

Consider posting to queues. Check out RabbitMQ. Node.js does have a [rabbitmq client](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node).

Post a message to the queue when a row is updated.

Make your node webapp listen to that queue.

Comment: It's act of POSTing which is tricky. Web application side is simpler to solve.